# Can I Create a Soft Data Validation Table of Joined Cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of data that makes up a list that would be good to use for data validation in another table. However, in the other table, I would like the fields to show a combination of two fields from the original table.

I have tried looking around Google and on here for a solution, but I can not seem to find anything similar to what I am after. Admittedly, a lot of my searching has brought up completely different questions regarding merged cells.

As you can see from the image, the data validation table merges the two cells to make each option. In this situation, I have created this using a seperate list of manually-created cells. I also know how to automatically create a cell that merges data from two cells, but I would like to know if I can create an algorithm that can be directly entered into the list sauce, as I prefer not having repeated data on a spreadsheet just for the purpose of data validation.

[image: This is an example, where "red" and "box" validate as "red box", and so on.]

[image: I am looking for something I can directly enter into the 'Source' field, under the 'Data Validation' window.]

Comment: Merge 2 columns first will be the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I can create an algorithm that can be directly entered into the list source, as I prefer not having repeated data on a spreadsheet just for the purpose of data validation

**No**, you can't combine two columns through validation rule. Your only option is to use a helper column. (which you can hide if you don't want to see it).